# GDPR data deletion: do I have a right to have the company specify which data it retained and why?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, data-ownership

I requested the DPO of a company to delete all my data under GDPR.

After a step of "account ownership" verification, it replied that:

> XXXX has deleted all of your personal data except where we are required by law to keep the data or have a legitimate interest in maintaining such data.`

1. Can I ask them to specify exactly which data they have deleted and which one they have retained?
2. Moreover, for the data that they retained, can I ask them to specify why they retained it? To provide a reason?